# How would i make this a decryption instead of an encryption?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

Wanna know how to get this from being a encryption code and using the same code to create a decryption.

I know it means that I have to reverse some of the instruction and re-order it but I can't figure out which ones need to be reordered and which ones don't.

(edit) Heres the full function to make things a bit clearer. Very new to stack overflow so apologies for any confusions.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------- ENCRYPTION ROUTINES -------------------------------------------------------------------------

void decrypt_chars (int length, char EKey)
{
  char temp_char;                       // Character temporary store

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)      // Encrypt characters one at a time
  {                                     
    temp_char = OChars[i];              // Get the next char from Original Chars array

    __asm                               
    {                                   
      push   eax                        // stores the "eax" register out onto the stack
      push   ecx                        // stores the "ecx" register out onto the stack
      push   edx                        // stores the "edx" register out onto the stack
                                        //
      movzx  ecx, temp_char             // zeroise "ecx" register and move values in "temp_char" varaible to "ecx" register
      lea    eax, EKey                  // copies address of values contained within the EKey varaible and moves it into "eax"register
                                        //
      push eax                          //
      push ecx                          //
                                        //
      call   decryptX                   // runs the function called "decryptX"
      mov    temp_char, dl              // move values in "dl" register into "temp_char" variable
                                        //
      add esp, 8                        // 
      pop    edx                        // removes the "edx" register from the stack
      pop    ecx                        // removes the "ecx" register from the stack
      pop    eax                        // removes the "eax" register from the stack
    }                                   //
    EChars[i] = temp_char;              // store encrypted char in the Encrypted Chars array
  }
  return;

  __asm
  {

  decryptX:
        push  ebp            // stores the pointer onto the stack

            mov   ebp, esp       // move values in "esp" register into "ebp" register
            mov   eax, [ebp + 12]// take value from the stack that is 8 bits above
                                 // from the pointer a putting it in the "eax" register
            mov   ecx, [ebp + 8] // take value from the stack that is 8 bits above 
                                 // from the pointer a putting it on ecx


            push  eax            // stores the Ekey address onto the stack
            xchg  eax, ecx       // puts temp_char's value into the EKey address register and Ekey address into temp_char register

            ror al, 1
            ror al, 1
            dec eax
            neg al


            mov   ebx, eax       // move temp_char value into "ebx" register
            pop   eax            // removes temp_char from the stack
            push  ebx            // stores temp_char value onto the stack
            pop   edx            // removes "edx" register value from the stack
            movzx ecx, [eax]     // zeroise "ecx" register and move the address stored in "eax" register to "ecx" register
            ror   cl, 1          // rotate "cl" register value in bytes to the right by 1
            xor cl, 0x96         // Exclusive OR (or XOR) the byte values within "cl" register with hex value 0x96 in binary
            push  ecx            // stores the Ekey address onto the stack
            and   cl, 0x7        // AND the byte values within "cl" register with hex value 0x7 in binary

            X:                       // Position X:

        add dl, 2            // add 2 to value within dl
            sub cl, 1            // subtract 1 from value within cl
            jg X                   // jump to "X" position
            pop   ecx            // removes "ecx" register value from the stack
            xor   ecx, edx       // exclusive OR (or XOR) the byte values within "ecx" register with the byte values within "edx" register
            mov[eax], cl         // move "cl" register value into the address stored in "eax" register.
            pop   ebp            // returning ebp back to the orginal value
            ret                  // return, end of encryptX function
  }

  //--- End of Assembly code
}
//*** end of encrypt_chars function
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What calling convention is this for?  32-bit `fastcall` with args in ECX, EDX?  And BTW, this isn't really inline asm, it's abusing inline asm to define a stand-alone function.  But you didn't provide the prototype.  Also, `rol al, 2` is legal on any CPU that can use 32-bit registers, so using `rol al, 1` twice is slow and pointless.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the response. Hopefully, my edit makes things a bit clearer for you to understand what's going on. The code is purposely made to do irrelevant things (such as rol al, 1 twice ) and is to be fixed will be fixed later on.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a homework assignment, then it's actually quite a tricky one. (Though I may have overlooked a simple approach.)

Let's focus on the effect this code has on **memory**. For simplicity I will assume you are not interested in the effect this code has on **registers**, though I cannot be sure within seeing the code calling this function.

```
encryptL:
    push  eax
    ...                ; ignoring this code because its effect on eax is undone by the following pop
    pop   eax
    ...                ; code not affecting eax
    movzx ecx, [eax]
    ...                ; code not affecting eax
    mov   [eax], cl
    ret
```

So in goes an address (`eax`). The byte at this address is put into `cl`, and after some transformations, `cl` is put back at the same address.
We need to figure out what those transformations are, and invert those.

```
    ror   cl, 1
    xor   cl, 0x96
    push  ecx
    ...                ; ignoring this code because its effect on ecx is undone by the following pop
    pop   ecx
    xor   ecx, edx
```

So a rotate and two xors are applied to `cl`.
Xor is an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)), so we do not have to change those two instructions.
The inverse of `rol` is of course `ror`, though that is not entirely true. The effect on the carry flag cannot be inverted, but in this case that effect is ignored, so we are good.

But what about all the code we ignored? On close inspection, you'll notice it is only there to calculate the value of `edx` that is used in `xor ecx,edx`.
Unfortunately, the original (unencrypted) value of `[eax]` is involved in that calculation.
When decrypting, the original value becomes the final value, i.e. the result of `xor ecx,edx`.
We seem to have a chicken-and-egg problem. How to perform the calculation when it depends on the result of that same calculation?

It should be clear that the effect of `[eax]` on the calculation of `edx`, is either 1 out of only 8 possible cases, due to this statement:

```
    and   cl, 0x7
```

That means we can use a loop to try all different possibilities, until we found one where the result of the calculation matches the value we found in `[eax]`.
That loop will be very similar to this loop found in the encryptor:

```
X:
    add   dl, 2
    sub   cl, 1
    jg    X
```

However, the exit condition of the loop will be different.

```
    mov   bl,0        ; using bl as a loop counter (similar to cl in original loop)
X:
    inc   bl
    add   dl,2        ; same as in the original loop
    mov   cl,[eax]    ; fetch encrypted byte from memory
    xor   ecx,edx     ; try transforming cl with the current value of dl
    xor   ebx,ecx     ; compare cl with the loop counter (bl)
    and   bl,7        ; only compare the 3 least significant bits
    jg    X           ; if not zero, try again with the next possible value of dl
```

Since `xor` is commutative and associative, we can rewrite this code.
Instead of incrementing `bl` until it matches `cl`, we will decrement `cl` until its (partially) transformed value is zero (modulo 8).

```
    mov   cl,[eax]    ; fetch encrypted byte from memory
X:
    add   dl,2        ; same as in the original loop
    sub   cl,1        ; same as in the original loop
    push  ecx
    xor   ecx,edx     ; transform cl with the current value of dl
    and   cl,7        ; only consider the 3 least significant bits
    pop   ecx         ; restore cl (without clobbering flags)
    jg    X           ; if equal, then we found the right starting point
```

As for the rest of the code, that can stay as it is. It is mainly the initial part of the calculation of `edx`, before `[eax]` becomes involved.

Here is the complete solution:

```
encryptL:
    push  eax
    xchg  eax, ecx
    neg   al
    inc   eax
    rol   al, 1
    rol   al, 1
    mov   ebx, eax
    pop   eax
    push  ebx
    pop   edx

    movzx ecx, [eax]
    push  ecx
X:
    add   dl,2
    sub   cl,1
    push  ecx
    xor   ecx,edx
    and   cl,7
    pop   ecx
    jg    X

    pop   ecx
    xor   ecx,edx
    xor   cl,0x96
    rol   cl,1
    mov   [eax],cl
    ret
```

Disclaimer: I did not test it, so it's quite likely it will not work. I will leave the debugging up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Ruud. Unfortunately your prediction was correct and the code gave the wrong output. I am a very big newbie when it comes to assembly and have near to no idea what to even do in the debugging. Your help is much-appreciated thank you as I got a clearer view of the code.

Comment: @SimzCoder Thank you for the edit. It proves that my initial assumption was wrong. Output registers _are_ relevant (`dl`), which means I'll have to completely rethink my strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Very apologetic for the inconvenience I have caused. Hopeful you could stay onboard and assist me more so that I get a better understanding of this piece of code and how to reverse it into making it a decryption.

Comment: @SimzCoder I think this actually makes everything a __lot__ simpler. But the line of thinking is similar to what I did. It doesn't take great assembly skills to figure this out, just logical thinking. It might help to draw a data flow diagram.

Comment: I think I'm nearing the answer to this problem. How does this Look to you? (Look in code edits)

Comment: You are more than welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but please do so by adding an answer; not by overwriting the question.